# Is there any plugin available from where i can auto generate entity relationship Diagram with eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to generate ER diagram from my sql file and it has to be auto generated by eclipse only. So I am in search of any plugin available for it.

Comment: see this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-erd/

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but be sure to read [What topics can I ask about](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This plugin for generating code out of an Entity-Relationship-Diagram (ERD). @Suchitkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the plug-in for this thing

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/dbeaver

you can get this from the market place in eclipse and connect your database to it. It will auto generate your ER diagram from the tables you have created.